# Convert IEnumerable<T> to List <T> Performance

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a web service that returns `List<SampleClass>`. I take data from database using LINQ-to-SQL as `IEnumerable<SampleClass>.` I then convert `IEnumerable<SampleClass>` to `List<SampleClass>`.

LINQ-to-SQL operation performance is OK, but `IEnumerable<SampleClass>` to `List<SampleClass>` takes some time to do the operation. Are there any solutions to get best performance from `IEnumerable<SampleClass>` to `List<SampleClass>`?

I read more than 3000 records from my database.

Thank you

Comment: ToList on IEnumerable makes the lazy sequence to eager and the query has to run. That could be one of the reason

Comment: Try to use IEnumerable all through the code if possible.

Comment: You can download the .NET source from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx and check out any method or class you want. In your case look for the ToList extension method in Enumerable.cs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> IEnumerable to List takes some time to do
>   the operation.

The reason you are getting the delay is because, when you do `ToList`, that is the time, when the actual query gets executed and fetches records from the database.

This is called [Deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

```
var query = db.yourTable.Where(r=> r.ID > 10);
var List = query.ToList(); //this is where the actual query gets executed.
```

When ever you iterate over the query using `ToList`, `ToArray` , `Count()` etc, that is when the actual query gets executed.

> Are there any solutions to get best performance from
>   IEnumerable to List? I read more than 3000
>   records from my database.

Without improving the query, No, you can't. But do you really need to fetch 3000 records, you may look into paging using [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Comment: thank you  very much.. but i need to fetch 3000 records at once.